# Control triggering of build jobs in RTC

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, rational-team-concert

In case of automatic triggers : Let’s assume IBM-RTC triggers jobs automatically based on schedule in Node A via Jenkins.

Questions:

- Is there any mechanism / plugin to detect the Node A availability & trigger job only when Node is available ?
- If Node A has some jobs waiting in Jenkins -- Is there a way to control triggering (such that job triggers after waiting jobs queue) in RTC until other jobs in Node A are completed with execution ?